# Best practices for keeping client data in sync with server

Tags: javascript, ajax, redux, synchronization

I have a view that shows recently updated objects chronologically, 10 items at a time.

To see next set of items (11-20, 21-30, 31-40 etc), this happens:

1. The user clicks on one of the buttons "Next" or "Previous"
2. The items are fetched via ajax and when received, the next view with the items is shown

I'd like to store all fetched items in application state if possible, to avoid a sluggish UX as the items are quite data heavy. Obviously the client data can easily get out of sync with the server.

When fetching new items - are there any patterns and/or tools that help keeping the order of items on the client in sync with the server?

I guess one solution is to feed the client on change via websockets, but are there any other viable solutions/techniques that supports the above scenario?

Comment: What did you do in the end ?